# iptables LOG only once

Tags: iptables, logger, logs

I noticed that there are data in the iptables log that I don't need, so I was wondering if it's possible to change some configuration so that the log has less information, thus reducing the log's size.

I would like log a write only once per IP during some times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hashlimit` match. Take a look on the options [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html).
In order to log once per source ip per hour, you would have, for example :

```
iptables -A INPUT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/hour --hashlimit-mode srcip -j LOG
```

Basing on your needs, you can use the following modes : `srcip, dstip, srcport, dstport` and the following length : `/sec, /minute, /hour, /day`.